# How to display an user-defined logo in a Metro dark themed application?

Tags: website-design, logo, interface-design

For a Windows application currently under development we have chosen a dark Modern UI theme. As I don't have any representative screenshot at hand, let's say our look and feel is somewhat similar to the [Mango Theme for Orchad](http://mangotheme.codeplex.com/) or the Windows 8 Metro:

[image]

As our clients will be allowed to integrate their logo In the start page of the application, I'm wondering how to integrate it so that it's not looking awkward?

As we won't have any control on the image file set by the client, what can be done to ensure that the logo looks as integrated as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet.. a white box for the logo. Not an ideal solution, but chances are most clients logos will be sitting on white.

You could provide the option of having a white background or a dark background if possible.